# NetBeans IDE 8.0.1 gives Redefinition failed with error 62 Check JVMTI documentation for this error code

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, netbeans

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0.1,jdk1.7.0_67,tomcat apache-tomcat-7.0.47. I have written a sample HelloWorld Spring MVC application and trying to profile the application. when i profile the application i get the following error

Redefinition failed with error 62
Check JVMTI documentation for this error code.

I have gone through the following links

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=191297
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59085

As said in the links i have set the property "-Xverify:none" in netbeans.conf. After setting the property i get the same error.

This is the default options present in netbeans.conf

netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Xverify:none"

Can some one please help me. Thanks in advance